# Esper EPL query like select statements in SQL

Tags: pojo, complex-event-processing, esper, epl

I am new to ESPER. I was checking for a SQL like query. Here is my scenario goes.
I need to handle a favorite use case. There will be one recommendation engine, which will recommend some URLs to the users in every 12 hours. If the user acts on the URLs by either marking it as favorite or not the events will go to ESPER.

1. If the user mark an URL as favorite, then CEP should tell the recommendation engine not to send same URL again.
2. If the user does not mark the URLs after recommended n number of  times(user is not interested), then also CEP will tell the recommendation engine not to send same URLs again.

Please suggest me how to proceed. I am thinking to use Favorite Event as a POJO.

Comment: Perhaps add a field that you check.  One that has a number of times you allow it to resurface to the user.  Decriment it each time it is shown to the user.  Once 0, don't show to the user?

Comment: Can you please mention which approach I should follow for the above use case ? Event-pattern matching or event stream queries ?